I transferred crypto from Revolut but I'm unaware of who the wallet service provider is. I have the wallet address but that's all
I've stupidly transferred crypto from Revoult to ramp. Then it seems I have no idea where it's gone from there. I have the wallet address and the hash transaction reports but I'm unsure what the wallet service provider is.
Is there a way of solving this horrible issue I have got myself into?
Any help would really really be appreciated. I don't have a clue here as my skills are on other fields.
My email is operationportal@proton.me
Thank you again for all your help and advice.
Jamie

This question is similar to: Old bitcoin purchase. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You will be receiving lots of email from fake recovery agents (scammers) who seek out victims who seem vulnerable to confusion, impulsiveness and panic.  You will find it helpful to read answers to Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?
